# How to replace days of weeks as weekdays and weekend in r?

Tags: r

Data

```
a = c('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday')
```

I am trying to replace days of weeks as weekdays/weekend using below code,

```
a = ifelse(a==c('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday'),'Weekday',
           'Weekend')
```

However I get the below warning message with expected results

```
Warning message:
In a == c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday") :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

is my approach correct ?is there a better approach ?

when I do this on a large data frame over 40,000 rows I don't get the expected result.

Comment: You need to use `%in%` instead of `==`

Comment: `==` only works with one comparison value, `%in%` compares to all elements of a vector in the way of `any(a == b, a == c, a == d, ....)`

Comment: You could also simplify the code by checking if a day is in the weekend: `ifelse(a %in% c("Sunday, 'Saturday'), 'Weekend', 'Weekday')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is almost correct.

You just need (as docendo discimus pointed out) `%in%` in place of `==`.

```
ifelse(a %in% c('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday'), 'Weekday', 'Weekend')
```

And then you could slightly simplify this with:

```
ifelse(a %in% c('Sunday', 'Saturday'), 'Weekend', 'Weekday')
```